# Determining the Big O complexity of a function

Tags: python, function, variables, time-complexity

What would the Big O complexity of my function be, O(n)?

```
def f(n):
    def g(m):
        m = 0
        for i in range(m):
            print m
    for i in range(n):
        g(n)
```

Comment: Won't it be nm, if m > 0?

Comment: As it stands, this is actually `O(n)` as `m` gets set to `0` before every loop call. No idea if that was intentional or not, but basically nothing gets printed.

Comment: I don't think it's `O(nm)`. Since the value of `m` is dependent on the iteration of `f(n)`, wouldn't it be something like `O(n^2)`? This is my gut feeling though, I didn't write it out on paper. See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Evaluating_run-time_complexity).

Comment: That is, of course, if you omit `m = 0`.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is O(n), because `m` is set as `0` in 3rd line and the for loop in `g(m)` never run.

If comment the 3rd line, i.e.

```
def f(n):
    def g(m):
        # m = 0
        for i in range(m):
            print m
    for i in range(n):
        g(n)
```

the time complexity would be O(n^2), since `print m` in `g(m)` would run `m` times and `g(n)` runs `n` times. Time complexity would be O(n*m). Here `m` = `n`, so O(n*m) = O(n^2).

If comment the 3rd line and modify the last line from `g(n)` to `g(i)`, i.e.

```
def f(n):
    def g(m):
        # m = 0
        for i in range(m):
            print m
    for i in range(n):
        g(i)
```

the time complexity would be O(n*(n-1)/2) = O(n^2). It's easy to find when calling `g(i)`, the `print m` would run `i` times. So, the sum running time of `g(0), g(1), ... , g(n-1)` is `0 + 1 + ... + n-1 = n(n-1)/2`, so the time complexity is O(n*(n-1)/2) = O(n^2).